# How to fix some Chinese characters that can’t be displayed in iOS 14?

Tags: display

[image]

[image]

How to fix some Chinese characters that can’t be displayed in iOS 14?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. To make your question easier to understand, please add information explaining what the screenshots are... Just guessing, but it looks like you are having trouble displaying a character from wiktionary.org on your iPhone. Is it this page: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/乴#Chinese? I've checked that page on macOS with Safari and Firefox and that character isn't displayed properly either, so it could be an issue with wiktionary.

Answer (score 2):

A device can normally only display characters which are included in the fonts installed on it.  Some Chinese characters are not included in the fonts that come with MacOS and iOS, so you would need to add fonts to see them.

The one you ask about appears to be U+22bf3. You can find the number by clicking on the blank character in the [Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B9%B4#Chinese). [This page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22bf3/fontsupport.htm) gives info about font support.

To add fonts to iOS you can use an app like [AnyFont](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/anyfont/id821560738).  But whether a particular app will use such added fonts is not guaranteed.

Comment: How did you find that Unicode and font?

Comment: How to install the font?

Comment: download one of the fonts via the webpage referenced above (e.g. the “Last Ressort”-font or any font with (almost) full unicode support like [Code2000](https://www.fontspace.com/code2000-font-f13284)). Then get Anyfont or the free [Fontcase](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/fontcase-manage-your-type/id1205074470?l=en) from the AppStore. open the app, import and install the font, follow the onscreen description to install the related font profile via system preferences.

Comment: But as [@Tom Gewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke) already pointed out, wether the font is used by a specific app depends on the app - quick check shows that they are available in Apple’s Pages, Keynote, Affinity Designer or Vectornator… YMMV.

Comment: @slartibartfast. The Last Resort font will not work, it is just placeholder generic  images that the system may use when a font does not have the actual character.